# How can I wait for a async Task method with a parameter and a return value?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I found a part of code like this here:

```
string stringExample = "";

async private Task myMethod (int MyNumber)
{
    var myString = await getStringFromIntAsync(myNumber);
    stringExample = myString;
}



private main()
{
    var t = Task.Run(async () => {await myMethod(123456);});
    t.Wait();
}
```

This works for me. 
But now is my question: How can i wait for a async Task Method with a return value like this:

```
async private Task<string> myMethod (int MyNumber)
{
    var myString = await getStringFromIntAsync(myNumber);
    return myString;
}
```

I tried it with Task.Run() but it does not work.

Thanks Agredo

Comment: See MSDN How to return a value from a task https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just plain block, then you can do that with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
private main()
{
    myMethod(123456).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

If `myMethod` returns a value:

```
private main()
{
    var result = myMethod(123456).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Note that blocking on asynchronous code is an anti-pattern, and should be avoided in real-world code. The notable exception to this rule is a Console application's `Main` method.